# Is a node process protected if its JavaScript files changes on the filesystem?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs project, and I run a local script

```
node somethingThatTakesVeryLong.js
```

is it safe for me to change the file's content (e.g. by switching a branch via git) while this process is running? Has node loaded all JavaScript files into RAM of the current context or is there a change it may load content from a changed file (e.g. due to an import that only happens after the file system has already changed)?

Basically: Can I trust a node process to run safely even if I remove / change its underlying files? Or can this lead to side-effects?

I am wondering if I can continue to work on a new branch while something runs in the background or if I must clone the project anew.

Comment: it really depend on how you are reading your file, could add information about that ?

Comment: If node hits a `require()` after you've changed the contents of your disk, I imagine the new file would be required in instead of the old one since node would never have had reason to look at that file yet.

Comment: @Nicolas I am not talking about reading a file via the File System component of node, but about the JavaScript files themselves that are loaded via the execution of node itself. Basically, how does node loads the JavaScript files and are those cached?

Comment: If this file depends on another file, and the require is inside an if condition, then some files might not have been loaded.  IOW:  `if (something) { require('xyz'); }`,  xyz will not yet be in memory,.

Comment: It would depend.  If you have conditional `requires` you might accidentally change the script before it's loaded.

Comment: @Keith That's a good example to make a contrived example to test that locally in order to get a definitive answer.

Comment: I just tested it using a loop and a `console.log`. If you run a file and then edit it's content, it will **NOT** be updated, meaning it is successfully store in RAM. It is important to keep in mind what @Keith said, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example were something is not yet loaded, and you will get the modified version.

file1.js

```
require('./file2');
```

file2.js

```
console.log("Waiting 10 seconds");
setTimeout(() => {
  require('./file3');
}, 10000);
```

file3.js

```
console.log("this is file3");
```

So if you run `node file1`, and within 10 seconds modifiy file3, it will have the new modified version.

But then lets say we modified file1.js.

```
require('./file3');
require('./file2');
```

And then run again, if you alter file3, it will be the same after the timeout, this is because node.js uses a cache, so only loads files once.